# JAVA domain classes creation from SQLite database

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I have an SQLite db containing many tables. I want to create Java domain classes for the same db. I used Hibernate tools in Eclipse with the dialect downloaded from this site http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/. I was able to create classes, but the data types for many fields are not correct. For example, if the data type in SQLite is `timestamp` then in the domain class it is created as `String`! I expect it to be `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Are there other tools that will do this?? OR is this a problem with the dialect??

Comment: Sounds like a bug - did you report it to the Hibernate project?

Comment: sqlite doesn't support datetime types, internally they are stored as string, typechecking and converting is left to the application, likewise typenames can be choosen completely free. If the types in the schema don't match what the library (hibernate-sqlite) is expecting, it can't do a conversion. Maybe you should post your database schema?

Comment: @mata are you saying that sqlite doesn't have date datatype...then why in sqlite manager it is showing that the type of my column is timestamp??

Comment: Yes, it's true, it [dosn't have a datetime type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). It has some support for datetime functions, that's it. Also, you can store any type in any colum, no matter of the definition, data types in sqlite are only a recommandation, they're not enforced.

Comment: @ARUNK.S The type of a column is whatever you have written there; SQLite Manager just shows that string. You could use a type "FLUFFY BUNNIES".

Comment: so for creating domain classes in java ...what should I do??